# How to search words in Array List by keywords?

Tags: java, arraylist

Does anyone know how to search word form ArrayList by keyword? If the programfind the word, returns the found word as many times as it occurs, applying paging and limiting the result to the input data.

For example:

Input data:

(2, 1, " ")

Result:

Items: University, Java; Total items 11; Pages 6

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

        arraylist.add("University");
        arraylist.add("Java");
        arraylist.add("JavaScript");
        arraylist.add("PHP");
        arraylist.add("HTML");
        arraylist.add("CSS");
        arraylist.add("Spring");
        arraylist.add("Vue");
        arraylist.add("Angular");
        arraylist.add("CSS");
        arraylist.add("CSS");

        int pageSize = 2;
        int pageNumber = 0;

        int from = Math.min(0,pageNumber * pageSize);
        int to = Math.min(arraylist.size(),(pageNumber+1)*pageSize);

        arraylist.subList(from,to);

        System.out.println(pageSize);
        System.out.println(pageNumber);

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter keyword");
        String input = userInput.nextLine();
```

Comment: What's the pattern for `Enter keyword` ? it will be one word to search or a list of words separated by space ? Also you need exact match or even partial ?(case sensitive also ?) What is page ?

Comment: `Items: University, Java; Total items 11; Pages 6` please clarify since any relation with keys are on first 3 records, but from here the result is not the one specified (maybe `total 3, pages 2`)

Comment: The keyword is only one word. "PageSize" means how many words are stored on one page.

Comment: The example means: (words per page: 2; page number: 1; keyword: " ") - this is the input data from user.

Comment: even using a loop over list you could count easily occurrences `for(String s: arrLst) { if(s.equals(input_key)) count++ }`

Answer (score 1):

Since cannot figure out the entire requirement even with additional explanations, maybe the following code will fit your needs.

```
public class TestOccurencePerPage {
    
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        arraylist.add("University"); 
        arraylist.add("Java");       
        arraylist.add("JavaScript"); 
        arraylist.add("PHP");        
        arraylist.add("HTML");      
        arraylist.add("CSS");
        arraylist.add("Spring");
        arraylist.add("Vue");
        arraylist.add("Angular");
        arraylist.add("CSS");
        arraylist.add("CSS");
        String key="CSS"; 
        int[] test1 = getOccurencesPages(arraylist,2, key);
        //11 entries last 2 CSS are on different pages(5 and 6)
        //so each count individually onPage_counter  
        int[] test2 = getOccurencesPages(arraylist,6, key);
        int[] test3 = getOccurencesPages(arraylist,20, key);
        System.out.format("key=%s, total=%s, onPages=%s ,pageSize=%2s, listSize=%s\n",
                           key,test1[0],test1[1],2,arraylist.size());
        System.out.format("key=%s, total=%s, onPages=%s ,pageSize=%2s, listSize=%s\n" ,
                           key,test1[0],test2[1],6,arraylist.size());
        System.out.format("key=%s, total=%s, onPages=%s ,pageSize=%2s, listSize=%s\n" ,
                           key,test1[0],test3[1],20,arraylist.size());
        
        
    }
    public static int[] getOccurencesPages(List<String> lst,int pageSize, String key)
    {
        //[0]-Occurrences,[1]-occur in n-pages
        int result[] = {0,0};
        //track for pages 
        //if word have more the 1 occurrence per page 
        //will not be added multiple time on page counter for same page)
        boolean flag=false;
        
        //element index is needed at onPage 
        //so foreach is not fit so well without adding additional var 
        //to track element index
        for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
        {
            if(i%pageSize==0) flag=false;
            if(lst.get(i).equals(key))
            {
                //count total occ
                result[0]++;
                //count occ per pages
                if(!flag)
                {
                    result[1]++;
                    flag=true;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output

```
//last 2 CSS are on different pages so each count 
key=CSS, total=3, onPages=3 ,pageSize= 2, listSize=11
//last 2 CSS are on same page so both count as 1
key=CSS, total=3, onPages=2 ,pageSize= 6, listSize=11
//all CSS are on the same page so all(3) count as 1 
key=CSS, total=3, onPages=1 ,pageSize=20, listSize=11

//pageSize can be even greater then listSize 
//meaning : there are still places for additional elements on page_1
//adding "CSS" till fill entire page_1, will not modify onPages_result
```